# PCB 0402/TQFN pad design

Tags: pcb, pad, stencil

I am currently designing a product which uses 0402 passives and other fine-pitch parts. As the PCB-space required is a major design goal I want to reduce the footprints. High production yield is also a big concern.

My PCB house requires a minimum solder mask width of 0.1mm/ minimum pullpack NSMD of 50um and has no specifications regarding the stencil, other than the thickness of 100um (0.1mm) (I would like to single source and provide the stencil to the assembler.) Furthermore, they specify a tolerance of +/- 0.1mm (6s) regarding the soldermask positioning relative to the copper. Please see the specifications [PCB specifications.](https://www.multi-circuit-boards.eu/fileadmin/user_upload/downloads/leiterplatten_design-hilfe/Multi-CB-Leiterplatten_Basic-Design-Rules_en.pdf)

My PCB assembly partner does not have any recommendations beyond IPC (I would rather not change the partner.)

**0402 Passives:**

Per my research I settle on the following design according to:

[IPC-7351](https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_C1002_X7R_SMD.pdf) Page 11 - Table 3 - Row 1 -> Interpolation between Level B and Level C.

[Stencil Design](https://smtnet.com/library/files/upload/Stencil-Design-for-Lead-Free-SMT.pdf) Page 3 - Figure 5 - 30/40/30 Stencil design adapted to 33/33/33.

[image: Footprint 0402 - Grid 0.1mm]

The figure shows the current 040 design. The grid is 0.1mm.

The parts use are  0402 resistors and low-profile capacitors.

Question: I am concerned by interpolating the IPC table and using the high-density specification.
Are there any "little tricks" to further help with the yield?

**TQFN-24-EP:** Also a 3x3mm TQFN-24-EP package is used in my design.

Please see the dimensions:

[Recommended Landpattern](https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/land_patterns/90-100089.PDF)

[Package Dimensions](https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/package_dwgs/21-100264.PDF)

As my final PCB width is just 3.9mm I needed to change some land pattern dimensions. The main reduction was done on the center pad and the outer four "triangle-pads". Please see the image:

[image]

The image shows the footprint used. Please note the marked via on the center pad. The grid is 0.1mm.

**Questions:** I am concerned that there will be issues with a good connection and reliable/high yield assembly on the center pad as there is a via (0.2mm Drill, 0.5mm PCB-thickness, soldermask on bottom) close by. I therefore did extend the stencil over the via. The chip supplier recommends a 1.7x1.7mm center pad (mine is 0.8x0.8mm.) I also removed the "triangle-pads" and designed them as "standard pads." I have concerns regarding a high yield/reliable assembly and also routing different tracks below the soldermask. **Are there any obvious "design problems" within this approach a beginner like me does not notice?**

**Hand-soldering:** My design does include a connector that has to be hand soldered on the PCB edge. The pins and pads are rather close to the components. Please see the image.

[image]

The connector pins (diameter 0.5mm) are "marked" in blue. Grid is still 0.1mm.

**Question:** As I am worried about the yield by doing hand-soldering so close to the 0402 passives: Are there any tricks you recommend to aid the assembler? We did not yet talk about this topic.

**Edit 1:**

I found another good document providing information: [QFN Assembly Tips](https://smtnet.com/library/files/upload/defect-free-qfn-assembly.pdf)

**Edit 2:**  As per @tobalt 's recommendations I redesigned the layout. Below the top and bottom copper is shown.

[image: Bottom Copper]

[image: Top Copper]

Comment: Hi having tented vias right under the exposed QFN pad is not a reliable insulation strategy. I suppose this could affect you yields. But one of the bigger space safers is usually more layers..How many do you have and did you consider using more ? Also consider via-in-pad for the vias that are now under the central tab..In general that via positioning can be greatly optimized

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Currently this a four layer design. Routing space on the inner layers is plenty. I would rather like to keep the layer count down - 6layers is an option. Via-In-Pad (filled & capped) is an issue due to cost. 

Could you please elaborate "In general that via positioning can be greatly optimized"?

I am thinking about moving the vias close to the center pad - same thought?

Comment: I wasnt talking about filled vias, but regular vias in pad - no extra cost. Bottom side can be tented..That way they dont suck up that much solder, esp. at only .5 mm thickness and aren't really a yield concern (IMHO, I am sure others disagree). I would move vias *out* There are often consecutive pins with needlessly long trace. Just put the via in there. In others cases it looks like you can put the via outside the IC

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @tobalt If i do understand correctly: You do recommend to place a via smack in the center between two pins of the TQFN (If same signal)? I can see this solution when the via is placed outside of the "solder mask removed" area - so my question: Do you think, that there will be issues with solder wicking if the via is moved on the pins directly (the wa i did interprete your commen - may be wrong here)

Comment: yes, if you put it between two pads, it will be even partially tented, which helps against wicking. But even vias that aren't tented on the top and with their hole directly in a pad, I would expect no issues here. It is advantageous though, to tent them on the bottom side. Essentially, move all the vias out of the zone under the exposed tab and place them elsewhere. With some optimization, I think they all fit somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your response @tobalt Do you have any literature or other sources related to this approach on hand - just curious? May I also ask if you have any other recommendations for my questions?